# Convert any number in clojure to floating point number

Tags: clojure, numbers

So I have this problem: I am making calculations with each element in a vector. Depending on the numbers in the vector the resulting vector may contain rationals, floats, scientific floats, big integers, integers. I need to convert all of them to floating point numbers or rounded integers. The resulting text is an SVG that will be sent to the client and those numbers are part of a path. Can I do it with something built in or should I roll my own function?

The problems with format are that it is a thin wrapper around the java Formatter class. This means that big ints are not handled since clojure has its own implementation.

On the other hand cl-format (which should be the primary choice actually) formats everything well except for rationals - 4/5 is converted to 4/5.0. Maybe I am doing something wrong with cl-format.

I tried type hinting the whole vectors (which will be needed anyway) as doubles, but the results keep returning as rationals.

Please help if I am missing something.

Answer (score 6):

It is not the job of a formatter to convert your datatypes, you should ensure the data has the type you want to print before handing it to the formatter.

Type hinting is not a type conversion or coercion, it is a hint to the compiler about what args are most likely to come in at runtime.

The function you want is `double`.

```
user=> (double 42)
42.0
user=> (map double [1.0 1 1.1M 2/3])
(1.0 1.0 1.1 0.6666666666666667)
```

Also, if you are type hinting the entire vector, you should not be using a vector, you should be using  `double-array`. Vectors are not specialized in any way by the type of their contents.